# Parametrized pattern matching issue

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

Suppose I have the following type hierarchy

```
sealed trait Animal

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
case class Cat(age: Int) extends Animal
```

Then if given `as: List[Animal]` I want to drop all the first encounters of cats then I can do

```
as.dropWhile {
    case d: Dog => false
    case _ => true
}
```

But when trying to parametrized this kind of search like this:

```
def findFirst[A <: Animal](as: List[Animal]): List[Animal] = {
    as.dropWhile {
        case a: A =>  false 
        case _ => true
    }
}
```

the compiler seems to erase the `A` type.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Take a look to the available resources regarding this topic: https://squidarth.com/scala/types/2019/01/11/type-erasure-scala.html

Comment: You may use a `ClassTag` but that will only work as long as `A` will never be generic itself.